# What's the difference between being in a simultion vs base reality

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, existence, argumentation

Having articles like Bostrom's "Simulation argument" gives us the probability that we are almost certainly living inside a simulation.

Putting aside the emotional, intuitive discomfort about it, what is so bad in being simulated ? (Obviously aside from the possibility being in a hell simulation of something similar)

Comment: First off, welcome to philosophy.se. Can you reword "gives us the probability that we are almost certainly"? Does this differ from just saying "We are most likely" or "We might be"? There's a jarring oddity in talking of probability and then certainty there.

Comment: I don't mind being in a simulation. What bothers me is being in a buggy one.

Answer (score 1):

Being in a simulation gives one less confidence about the rationality of reality and our ability to [scientifically?] penetrate it to its 'base', or *ad infinitum*, if it is infinitely complex as David Bohm suggests in [Causality and Chance in Modern Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000OYEYCM). Any simulation we do of reality will of necessity be smaller then our own reality, either in complexity or scope. How would creatures inside such a simulation have even equal power to explore reality, as we do?

Another argument is that if we are a simulation with a purpose, then those running the simulation may not want us to proceed past a certain technological or scientific point. Such progress may violate the very purpose of the simulation. Imagine, for example, that a company wishes to advertise its product with maximum effectiveness. Well, perhaps it would wish to squash technological innovation which would render its product obsolete. And so, it could run advertising simulation research and squash anything in the simulation which would destroy its utility.

Answer (score -2):

Who says it's bad? It provides me with great comfort to see that we, primitive humans already have the technology to do quite complex real-time simulations, therefore it is very plausible that a more advanced civilization in a superior world simulates this world. In this case there are one or maybe more positive alternatives, from our viewpoint.

There are two ways as I see it:

1. We are more than parts of the simulation, our consciousness is
   somehow connected to the "mother-world", . - one we all hope for
2. We are products of the simulation, self-awareness is just a strange illusion that happens over a certain levels of algorithmic complexity paired with biological representation. We are nothing more than organic machines. - one science points to

So as long as you keep the 1st option in mind you can think of simulation theory as a new seed of hope for an afterlife.